# php fatal error with wp_remote_post() function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I try to remotely add a post entry in wordpress (from a website outside my wordpress site). This is the code I use:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://mywpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

$user = 'wpuser';
$pass = 'xxxx yyyy xxxx yyyy'; //Password for use with Application Passwords Plugin

$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $user . ':' . $pass ),
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
];

$body = [
    'status'  => 'draft',
    'type'    => 'post',
    'title'   => 'Title of my Post',
    'content' => 'My Content',
];

$args = [
    'headers'     => $headers,
    'body'        => $body,
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => true,
    'cookies'     => [],
];

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    print_r( $response->get_error_message() );
}
?>
```

The error log on the provider's web server says: *"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_remote_post() in ..."*
I checked php.ini -> cURL support is enabled, allow_url_fopen is on. I also added the Rewrite rule in .htaccess. Any ideas on what to check or do?

Comment: if your code is running outside wordpress you won't have wordpress functions,

Comment: O.K., I moved my script inside the WP environment. Now wp_remote_post works, but I get the error **you are not allowed to create posts as this user - Auth issue...**.
As mentioned in many other questions on stackoverflow, I installed the Basic Authentication plugin & the application passwords plugin, added the Rewrite rules into .htaccess and checked php.ini. Everything should work, but the Authentication issue remains. Any other ideas?